# Сonstruction "Do you mind"

Tags: grammaticality, construction

Your room mate asks: “Do you mind if I smoke?”. 
But, you HATE smoking. What would you say? “Yes” or “No” ?

I think correct answer is "Yes".
My answered correctly?

Comment: You could also say: Yes, I do (mind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say

> "Yes, I am allergic to smoking. So please do it while I am out of here."

Or

> "No, not at all."